# How to extract Unique keys from a Hash Table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hashtable

I am trying to print unique, individual keys from a hash table onto a   tag with javascript.

My Code:-

```
 for (var key in name) {
       // write  name in the side panel. //
       $('div.hidden').append('<p>' + key + '</p>').css("color", "white");
       }
```

This works. However, it prints my keys multiple times.

Can any one tell me how I can improve my code, to show all keys in my hashtable only once.???

Example of my output:-

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

so repeats it abt 3 times.

**My data structure:-**

```
{
    'scholar': [ ],
    'contributor': [ ]
and so on.
}
```

Basically, names of awards and what dates were they achieved on. Some awards have a single date, others a list of dates.

key is the name of the award. value is the date/s of the achievement.

To build this, i originally had two arrays, then i iterated through the names array and built the final result:- if the final result already contains the key, push the corresponding date on to its value otherwise set a new key to an array containing its corresponding date. (creating the final hash table)

something like:

```
var resultVal = {};
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
    if(resultVal[names[i]]) {
        resultVal[names[i]].push(dates[i]);
    } else {
        resultVal[names[i]] = [dates[i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of data? In any case duplicated keys are not valid, by definition a "key" must be unique, so I would start solving the problem where the data comes from rather that messing with messy data and adjusting the output.

Comment: op is using for-in on an array. use an array.unique prototype method to kill repeats

Comment: I know! "key" is unique, and when I use breakpoints.. I can see that the keys are unique. However  no Idea why it repeats it 3 times. bizarre.

Comment: @dandavis how do I use that method in my case?

Comment: Yes please, show the data structure

Comment: data structure :-

'key' : 'list of values'
 name: list of dates

Comment: I don't think `name` is an array, otherwise its keys would be numeric..

Comment: ok I updated how I created my data structure.

Comment: Maybe it dragging some properties from prototype chain? What happens if you add the condition `if (name.hasOwnProperty(key)) $('div.hidden').append('<p>' + key + '</p>').css("color", "white")`

Comment: you still don't show the array you are iterating... If you do, i'll update my answer.

Comment: you want me to print the whole array? 

it has abt 300 unique keys.

Comment: 5 or ten should be plenty, i just need to know the shape of the elements.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: When I do your method , now my output is numbers.... 1,2,3,.....1,2,3....1,2,3..... repeat each element 3 times.

Comment: @dandavis:

'scholar' : '1/3/2010','3/5/2010','6/3/2011'<br>
'commentator' : '5/6/2010'<br>
'tumbleweed' : '1/2/2009'<br>

Comment: is this a javascript question? what is the question? i still see no names variable, and where do the ABCD... value you refer to come from? Please cleanup your question; post the code thats giving you the issue, and explain what you want instead.

Comment: yes this is a javascript question as mentioned in the title.

what do u mean what is the question? I tried to provide every bit of info that you wanted. i will clean up my question.

and the variables come from an SQL query via jquery and a webmethod. These all seem to work fine, because I use them to draw on a html5 canvas. only when I trying to print the names on the <div class> which is attached to a side panel I have created on my page, do I get the repetition.

Comment: you are presenting me with a single array. [1,2,3,4,3,2,1]...however mine is like ['a:1,2,3,4', 'b:3,5,6,8' , 'c:2', ....]

Comment: @Philo: How many divs do you have in your document with `class="hidden"`?

Comment: I have 3 divs with class = hidden.

Comment: And everything appears three times.  Coincidence...?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should do you right:

```
Array.prototype.unique=function unique(){var r=this;var t=[];var mx=r.length;for (var z=0; z< mx; z++){if(t.indexOf(r[z])==-1){t[t.length]=r[z];}}return t;};

 //ex usage:
var name2=[1,2,3,4,3,2,1]
name2.unique().map(function(key){
       // write  name in the side panel. //
       $('div.hidden').append('<p>' + key + '</p>').css("color", "white");
  return key;
 }); // == [1,2,3,4]
```

NOTE that the variable name "name" cannot bind to Array.prototype for some weird reason, but (almost) any other name will work. answer updated, tested. works on any array of primitives.

Comment: i get the error 

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'unique'

and i didn't do the down vote.

Comment: yeah, "name" cannot be an array that gets array methods. that's a new one on me. If you need it to work in IE8 or before, use a for loop or a [].map shim.

Comment: my array name is actually called "d_name"

Comment: I even tried your hardcoded array - and I get 5 repetitions of each element. Which makes me think, there is something wrong other than the array itself.

Comment: @Philo - Are you sure the loop itself isn't being called 5 times?

Comment: bizarre :- when I use the hard coded name2.unqiue() method, outside of any of my loops I get the correct output - 1,2,3,4

but if I used my original name d_name.unique() method, I get unique is not supported property error. which makes me think that there is something wrong with my data structure.

Comment: i was thinking the same thing. i'd like to help you, but i don't understand what data you have and what data you want. if you can post the most stripped-down example and a sample hand-coded desired end structure, i'm sure anyone one here can whip it out in about 2.5...

Comment: dude, I posted my data multiple times.... its a hash table, obtained from 2 arrays. one array contained names, and another list of dates when those names happened. 

the final hash table contains names (as keys) and their occurrence date( as values)....

end goal I desire, is to print unique names on a side panel with a <div class>

Comment: ok, I was finally able to solve my issue (work around not a solution). 

The unique() method works on arrays and not on a hash-table {key:values} kind of data structure. So I just extracted my keys, created an array out of it. Sorted the array. and then used the unique{} method. Thanks for your help dan.

Comment: @Philo - it's confusing because JS doesn't have hash tables, only Objects, and those Objects always have unique keys, eg: Object.keys({a:1,a:1}). Only the array can have duplicates, and the unique() method i posted removes duplicates in Arrays. The one caveat is if you have an array of objects. If you want an array of Object keys, Object.keys() or a polyfill does that for you. Anyways, glad we got it working...

Comment: javascript and hashtables : http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html

Look under Objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome, give your object a different name instead of `name`. Apparently in Chrome it has some meaning and the `for ... in...` loop produces quite different results in it than in other browsers.

Comment: my object is actually called 'd_name'. thanks for the information. future reference":)